# Next-auth session immediately becomes unauthenticated after successful login in a Next.js app

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I'm using next-auth in my Next.js app for authentication. After successfully logging in, I'm immediately redirected to the login page, indicating that the session has become unauthenticated.

Relevant code snippets:

_app.tsx:

```
const App = ({
    Component,
    pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
    emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache,
}: any) => {
    const getLayout = Component.getLayout;
    // ... other logic ...

    if (session.status === "unauthenticated") {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
    } else {
        // Render the main component
    }
};
```

Layout.tsx:

```
const session = useSession();
const router = useRouter();

if (session.status === "loading") {
    return <>loading...</>;
}
if (session.status === "unauthenticated") {
    router.push("/login");
}
```

login.tsx (token callback):

```
async function token(token, user) {
    return Promise.resolve({
        accessToken: token.accessToken,
        refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
        accessTokenExpires: token.accessTokenExpires,
        user,
    });
}
```

Behavior:

Upon successful login from the login.tsx component, I'm redirected to a page wrapped with the Layout.tsx component. Almost immediately, the session status becomes unauthenticated, causing the Layout.tsx to redirect back to the /login page.

I've tried adjusting the token's expiration time (expiresIn) to different values, but the issue persists.
There is no other logic in my app that pushes to the login route after logging in.

Question:

What could be causing the session to become unauthenticated immediately after logging in? How can I ensure the session remains authenticated for the user after a successful login?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the `SessionProvider`. See https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example#configure-shared-session-state